# IConvertible Vs. implicit/explicit operator type conversions?

Tags: .net

I have created a class of type Base36, and am coding the type conversion functions.  Is there a benifit to implementing IConvertible, or should I define out my type conversions using static implicit/explicit operators?

```
    public static implicit operator long(Base36 value) {
        return value.NumericValue;
    }
```

Edit: I guess I am also looking for what each method provides to me.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is, you should provide both, if you feel it's worth the effort and the benefit.